# Grails create routines

Tags: grails, groovy, routines

In my Grails project i need to create a routine so that, in xx seconds, i need to query the database and send an email to the found users. This routine must be running all the time.

I want to know the best way to do this, i'm looking for the easiest way, using plugins or not. I have found similar answers to this same question, but all of them were not clear enough because my knowledge with Grails/Groovy is short.

thanks in advanced,
RR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easily done with the [Quartz plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz)
To install, add

```
compile ':quartz:0.4.2'
```

to the plugins section of BuildConfig.groovy, then run `grails compile`, or if you're on Grails 2.0 run `grails refresh-dependencies`, to install the plugin.
Then you can create a new job with `grails create-job my.package.My` , and you will get a generated class `MyJob`. Inside the `execute` method you can write you code, or better: call a service where you place your logic. The service will be automatically injected into your job, so all you need to do is to add `def myService` at the top of your job class (if you service is called MyService)

And for sending mail, there's the [Mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail)